# VSCode - experimentalDecorators is [ts], but no typescript is used

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode with eslint and prettier.
Last week i've got warnings not only from [eslint] but also from [ts] (typescript?).

**I don't write typescript!** I don't have any tsconfig.json file in the project. I'm working with React.

I already tried to uninstall the vscode, deleted all the preferences files in the /use/.vscode directory, uninstalled all the addons and reinstalled just the eslint and prettier again.
Even on a clean vscode, without any addon, i still get the [ts] warnings!

How can i disable it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to disable typescript compiler checks in .js files, set `javascript.validate.enable` setting in your user/workspace settings to false.

You can also enable/disable this per file or in `jsconfig.json'. Check [these docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_type-checking) for more details.

Comment: Thanks,
I do want an ESLINT validation, but not the TS one.
Isn't disable it will also disable both?

Comment: It should disable ts validation only.

Comment: I disabled bot `javascript.validate.enable` and `typescript.validate.enable`. The VSCode still shows me the `[ts]` warnings.

Comment: I have no other idea. You can try with new workspace and see if it still happens. Also ensure that your workspace settings doesn't override user settings.